# Rewrite /anything/index.php to /anything/ in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to rewrite /anything/index.php to /anything/ in Nginx. I've Bing'd but nothing helps. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx redirect loop, remove index.php from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687288/nginx-redirect-loop-remove-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/index.php /$1/ last;
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect; it'll cause a redirect loop.