# nginx redirect loop, remove index.php from url

Tags: php, nginx, url, redirect, nginx-config

I want any requests like `http://example.com/whatever/index.php`, to do a 301 redirect to `http://example.com/whatever/`.

I tried adding:

```
rewrite ^(.*/)index.php$ $1 permanent;

location / {
    index  index.php;
}
```

The problem here, this rewrite gets run on the root url, which causes a infinite redirect loop.

Edit:

I need a general solution

`http://example.com/` should serve the file `webroot/index.php`

`http://example.com/index.php`, should 301 redirect to `http://example.com/`

`http://example.com/a/index.php` should 301 redirect to `http://example.com/a/`

`http://example.com/a/` should serve the index.php script at `webroot/a/index.php`

Basically, I never want to show "index.php" in the address bar.  I have old backlinks that I need to redirect to the canonical url.

Comment: well a redirect loop is def a logical thing to happen, because both URL's are the same, the `whatever/` will call `index.php` because you most probably have an `index index.php` line above

Comment: I want to 301 redirect the external url, but internally serve the file index.php.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Great question, with the solution [similar to another one I've answered on ServerFault recently](https://serverfault.com/questions/568569/nginx-url-rewrite-rule/568902#568902), although it's much simpler here, and you know exactly what you need.

What you want here is to only perform the redirect when the user explicitly requests `/index.php`, but never redirect any of the internal requests that end up being served by the actual `index.php` script, as defined through the `index` directive.

This should do just that, avoiding the loops:

```
server {
    index index.php;

    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
        return 301 $1;
    }

    location / {

        # ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. Note that the usage of `if` as @cnst is using it is **not** evil.

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  It was the last piece of the puzzle to move from Apache to Nginx.

Comment: Great answer. I wonder how it could be done without the `if() {}` syntax and instead as a one liner? Anyway, for now, I modified it a bit to preserve the query string if any:  

`if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(?:.*)$") {`  
  `return 301 $1$is_args$args;`  
`}`

Comment: I think passing the query parameters should be allowed in it. Changing it to: 

if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(.*)") {
        return 301 $1$2;
    }

Comment: Nice one @Neo To avoid getting double slash // I changed a little 
 # Strip index.php to avoid duplicate content
    `if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(/?)(.*)") {
        return 301 $1$3;
    }`

Comment: And if you want this to work for `index.php`, `index.html`, and `index.htm` (the default nginx index stack), try:

`if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.(html?|php)\/?(.*)$") { return 301 $1$3; }`

Comment: I've made a number of changes to the provided answer, to more closely match the request. First, `$request_uri` already contains `$args`, which means a) you MUST account for them, b) you don't need to add them, given (a) is satisfied. Second, the `#fragment` MAY be passed to the request, and you MUST account for it as well. Third, you most likely want to capture FIRST `index.php`. Thus, the matcher I set for the leading part of URI is a non-greedy capture of anything that isn't a request delimiter.

Comment: This still leaves unresolved the issue of request delimiters passed in clear text when a full URL passed as request, including scheme, host and auth data. But such applications are rare and I've intentionally left it out for clarity.

Comment: @AnrDaemon, good points!  However, can you clarify when `#fragment` may be passed to the request?  I was not aware of that being a possibility.

Comment: nginx is a generic server, and you'd be surprised, how "generic" someone can be, since HTTP specification does not explicitly forbid passing a fragment to the server. Also the fragment may appear in the URI as the result of redirection, internal or external. In either case, using `#` as the separator is safe from protocol POV, as, under normal circumstances, it SHOULD NOT appear in the request unencoded.

Comment: Ok. Dear KarmaOverflow users, can someone point to me, where in the http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13471659 I've deviated from the original poster's intent?… Which line, character or whitespace is a, ekhm, "deviation"?

Comment: Thanks @Jerem , your suggestion was the most useful and worked wonders for me.

Comment: Don't we need to add a slash to cover it?
`if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php/?$") {`

Comment: @Jacob Ford How do I need to modify the expression to match index.html and index without html (as extension)?

Comment: @AndrewK — `if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index(\.(php|html))?/?$") { return 301 $1; }`

Comment: @AndrewK also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399739/1122270.

Comment: Nice answer, except, I don't want a redirect, I just want to quietly redirect (rewrite) `http://host.com/a/index.php/b/c?d=e&f=g` to `http://host.com/a/b/c?d=e&f=g`

Answer (score 2):

Try that

```
location ~ /*/index.php {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*) http://www.votre_domaine.com/$1 permanent;
}
location /index.php {
    return 301 http://www.example.com/;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have first line mentioned below in your Nginx configuration file you don't have rewrite it again.

index  index.php index.html index.htm;

rewrite ^(/.*).html(?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;

rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri/ $uri =404;

This will remove .html from the URL and additionally will also remove "index" from home page or index page. For example -
https://www.example.com/index will be changed to https://www.example.com

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
location = /whatever/index.php {
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com/whatever/;
}
```

Another benefit from doing it this way is that nginx does a return faster than a rewrite.

Comment: I want something that works generally:  /a/index.php -301-> /a/, /b/index.php -301-> /b/