# Nginx - Wordpress redirect to default url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I have one problem about the redirecting I want to make redirect to example.com/12321.html to example.com?p=12321.

I was user before url typle like first number things after this i change my system to seo url with content name to url. Now i guest best system to redirect to ?p=

### What I Try

First i try to change that on .htaccess not working i use this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^([0-9]+)+[^.html]" "https://www.example.com?p=$1"
```

Than I thing to make that with nginx write this code on nginx server block

```
rewrite ^([0-9]+)+[^.html] https://www.example.com/$1 redirect;
```

I don't understant that is why not working, I check it already on https://regex101.com/r/pimHGN/1 showing working there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as a quick check, you could try a regex like the following for Apache:

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)\.html$ https://www.example.com?p=$1 [L,R=301]
```

And something like this for Nginx:

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)\.html$ https://www.example.com?p=$1 permanent;
```

This should match any page composed of digits `0-9` and `.html`.

The rule you posted wouldn't match on the `.html` part, which might be why it wasn't working.

Comment: Thank you for answer but it's not working i check it now :(

Comment: My bad, forgot the capture group and leading slash.

Answer (score 1):

Not too clear what you're trying to do, however, unless you have a `rewrite` rule that'd be removing `/` from `$uri` first, your rule of `rewrite ^([0-9]+)+[^.html] https://www.example.com/$1 redirect;` would never match, because it is impossible for `$uri` to not start with `/`, hence, `^([0-9]+)` would never catch anything.  (Additionally, `[^.html]` looks suspect as well — I have a feeling that it wouldn't do what you expect it might.)

The correct way may be:

```
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)\.html$ /?p=$1 redirect;
```

---

However, as per [nginx redirect loop, remove index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687288/nginx-redirect-loop-remove-index-php-from-url/21813759#21813759) and related, the following "loop" might be what you actually want:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/?p=([0-9]+)) {
    return 302 /$1.html
}
rewrite ^/([0-9]+)\.html$ /?p=$1;
```

The above code would ensure that the `/?p=` style is only used internally within nginx and the backend, whereas externally, everything always gets redirected to, and served from, the `.html`-style pages.