# Extending Nginx config on Beanstalk doesn't rewrite urls properly

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, url-rewriting, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an existing Laravel API application running on Beanstalk. It's been lagging in updates on EBS, so currently I'm in the process of upgrading the platforms and CI/CD for this app. There one remaining problem I'm running into, which leaves me scratching my head at the 'but it *should* work'-level.

**What I want**

All URLs containing https://example.com/index.php/endpoint to be redirected to https://example.com/endpoint and show the same content as https://example.com/index.php/endpoint would (incl. subsequent the URL's slugs)

**How I'm trying to do this**

Due to [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687288/nginx-redirect-loop-remove-index-php-from-url) by [cnst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1122270/cnst), I have the configuration below that seems to work for many (incl. some other online sources).

```
server{
    index index.php;

    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php/*(.*)$") {
        return 301 $1$2;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        # Remove from everywhere index.php
        if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php(/?)(.*)") {
            return 301 $1$3;
        }
    }

    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    if ($request_uri ~* "\/\/") {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

I'm putting this configuration in a file located at `my_project/.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`, which according to [AWS' documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html), should upload with the project and *extend* the nginx configuration. As far as I can tell, it does pick it up, since any typo will result in an error after `eb deploy`. I can also see on the server it has been added to `/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`.

**The Problem**

Even though the extending proxy.conf is being deployed and the configuration in it seems to be picked up, the application won't pick up the rewrite and leave the application URLs running with the `index.php` instead of the rewrite.

- `https://example.com/index.php/endpoint` → works
- `https://example.com/endpoint` → results in a server generated 404
- Nginx logs show `2021/02/12 14:23:24 [error] 7523#0: *35 open() "/var/www/html/public/api" failed (2: No such file or directory)` which tells me it has searched for a file and never tried running it through `index.php`.

**The Questions**

- What am I missing in my configuration?
- Or is it something about EBS that I overlooked or misunderstood?
- Is the `index.php` angry since I'm trying to hide its face from public view?

Answer (score 1):

Solution moved from the question to an answer:

> I gave it a weekend to see if anyone would know and went back to work.
>
> First thing, I did is see if Beanstalk was picking up *any*
> configuration, so I put an invalid variable in and see if that would
> break the server. It didn't...
>
> Second, I checked if my Beanstalk instance was actually using Nginx
> (default) or got switch to Apache (httpd) for some reason (it includes
> both). Via its GUI config I could easily tell it's Nginx.
>
> Third, I viewed the `nginx.conf` on the server and checked how other
> `.conf` files were being included. Part of it is seen here;
>
> ```
> http {
>     [...]
>     include       conf.d/*.conf;
>
>     map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
>         [...]
>     }
>
>     server {
>         listen        80 default_server;
>         access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
>
>         [...]
>
>         # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
>         include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Here lays the problem; I was including a file at the `conf.d/*.conf`
> level with a second nginx `server` configuration block, which is
> effectively overwritten with the standard `server` configuration block
> by Beanstalks own config.
>
> So there's two solutions here;
>
> 1. override the entire `nginx.conf` by including a new `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` in your project, where you extend the
>    server block with your own config
> 2. or, in my opinion more gracefully, add `.platform/nginx/elasticbeanstalk/proxy.conf` to your project,
>    extending the `server` block specifically (but remove any `server`
>    blocks from your own config)
>
> Solution 2 will gard that AWS can always update its default nginx.conf
> without you having to watch out for it (unless they change the
> location of the elasticbeanstalk configs).
>
> I did try putting my configuration in
> `.platform/nginx/elasticbeanstalk/proxy.conf` before, but that would
> break the server, since I was including a `server` block, causing it
> to double nest.
>
> Lesson here;
>
> - add `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` to override your entire Beanstalk Nginx configuration
> - add `.platform/nginx/conf.d/your_conf.conf` for any extensions to the `http` block
> - add `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/your_conf.conf` for any extensions to the `server` block (or nesting within)